# Tkinter Button does not execute command

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a button that opens local files from a users machine. I have my buttons set up and the function to open files is pretty simple. When clicking the actual button, nothing actually happens. The intended result should be a box that opens that shows local files.

Here's my program so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog

gui = Tk(className='musicAi')
gui.geometry("500x500")


def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', filename)

# create button
importMusicButton = Button(gui, text='Import Music', command = UploadAction, width=40, height=3, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff', activebackground='#0052cc', activeforeground='#aaffaa')
linkAccountButton = Button(gui, text='Link Account', width=40, height=3, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff', activebackground='#0052cc', activeforeground='#aaffaa')
settingsButton = Button(gui, text='Settings', width=40, height=3, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff', activebackground='#0052cc', activeforeground='#aaffaa')
helpButton = Button(gui, text='Help', width=40, height=3, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff', activebackground='#0052cc', activeforeground='#aaffaa')
# add button to gui window
importMusicButton.pack()
linkAccountButton.pack()
settingsButton.pack()
helpButton.pack()


gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you import `filedialog` using `import tkinter.filedialog`, you need to use `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` to execute `askopenfilename()`.

Change `import tkinter.filedialog` to `from tkinter import filedialog` or `import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog`.

Comment: oof thats embarrassing, that did the trick i'll accept the answer in 6 minutes since theres a timer for whatever reason

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the event object as parameters in Uploadfunction, use the bind method.

```
ImportMusicButton.bind(<"Button-1">, lambda:UploadAction())
```

In your UploadAction(event = None), remove the default value of an event parameter. Should be

```
def UploadAction(event):
    code goes here...
```

Comment: Normally you shouldn't use `bind` with the button. The `command` attribute works better because it will be triggered both by the mouse and via the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have perfect option for you.

Instead of using:
`import tkinter.filedialog`
you can use a better thing.

Use:
`from tkinter.filedialog import *`

Then you can remove the `filedialog` from `filename = filedialog.askopenfile()`.

Change it to:
`filename = askopenfile()`
:)